# How can I print test name in valgrind report?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm using valgrind to check memory leaks.
My application has two threads:

1. Main thread who running tests.
2. Worker thread who waiting for messages from main thread and
   executing commands according to the received message.

When memory leak is found by valgrind, if leak is related to the worker thread, valgrind report shows stack trace of the worker thread.
In order to fix such leak, I need to know which test caused the leak. The test name/ID is coming from the main thread trougth message queue.
Is it possible to add test name or ID to the valgrind report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we found is to use valgrind macros: `VALGRIND_DO_CHANGED_LEAK_CHECK`, `VALGRIND_COUNT_LEAKS`, `VALGRIND_COUNT_LEAK_BLOCKS` in order to determinate which test causes leak

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add test name or ID to the valgrind report?

No, it is impossible, as far as I know.

But you can attach to your application with gdb when memory leak is found by valgrind. Here is the description of how to do it in [valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver):

> If you want to debug a program with GDB when using the Memcheck tool,
>   start Valgrind like this:
>
> ```
> valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 prog
> ```
>
> In another shell, start GDB:
>
> ```
> gdb prog
> ```
>
> Then give the following command to GDB:
>
> ```
> (gdb) target remote | vgdb
> ```

Now you can find in stack trace the place where you receiving messages from main thread and print in gdb test name, ID or whatever you want.